How to move image from to left to the right?
Issue with Moving Image to the Right in HTML/CSS
I'm encountering a problem while trying to move an image to the right within a section of my HTML page using CSS. Despite attempting methods like using float and margin-left, the image refuses to budge from its original position. Here's a simplified version of my code:
HTML:
<section class="home">
    <div class="home-content">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="img-box">
        <img src="assets/img.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</section>

CSS:
.home {
    /* Styles for the section */
}

.home-content {
    /* Styles for the content */
}

.img-box {
    /* Styles for the image container */
    /* I've tried the following to move the image to the right */
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    float: right;
}

I've tried adjusting margins and using float: right, but the image remains stubbornly in its original position. How can I resolve this issue and successfully move the image to the right within the section? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
